# mod_speling not enabling case-insensitivity as expected

Tags: apache, mod-speling

I'm running Ubuntu 12 on two separate VPS accounts, and having the same problem on both.

- I've enabled the speling module via "a2enmod speling".
- I have both speling.load and speling.conf in /etc/apache2/mods-available, and they're both aliased in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled.
- `cat speling.conf` yields "CheckSpelling on", and `cat speling.load` gives "LoadModule speling_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_speling.so"
- I've also verified that /usr/lib/apache2/modules/ does indeed contain "mod_speling.so".
- I've restarted Apache repeatedly.

And yet - if I mis-capitalize a word in a URL, I get a 404. Isn't "CheckSpelling on" meant to eliminate this? Perhaps I've misunderstood.

I feel sure I've missed some silly step, but can't think what.

Comment: Rather than editing your post, I have to ask... did you spell 'spelling' correctly throughout your configuration process? I can't help but notice your ironic use of 'speling' here.

Comment: "speling" is correct.The module is called mod_speling. More info here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_speling.html

Answer (score 2):

This wasn't working for me all of a sudden as well, after it running fine for many years.

I changed my configuation directives from:

```
 CheckSpelling on
 CheckCaseOnly on
```

To:

```
 checkspelling on
 checkcaseonly on
```

And now it works again.  So make it all lowercase and see if that helps.

Comment: Better solution is to go to `00-base.conf in `\conf.modules.d` folder and remove the `#` from `LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so` and now `mod_speling.so` will load and work properly.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely mod_rewrite interfering with mod_speling, as spelling is not checked for urls which match mod_rewrite rules.

Check your httpd.conf, site configuration as well as .htaccess files for mod_rewrite rules which might be matching the urls you are trying to make case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

If your httpd.conf looks like this
[image: httpd.conf]

Don't add

```
LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
```

Even if that fixes the problem.. but rather go through all the directories of `conf.modules.d` folder and load up all the files and search for `mod_speling.so`, you'll find it in `00-base.conf` and remove the `#` hashtag from it and it will load now.

[image: module.d directories]
[image: 00-base.conf with mod-speling.so]
[image: LoadModule mod_speling.so fixed]